# Eclipse has a two-three second delay every time I switch files

Tags: android, eclipse

Ever since I uninstalled Eclipse and reinstalled it as part of the Android SDK bundle, there is a delay every time I click the tab for a different java or xml file. During this delay, I see a couple of buttons appear and disappear from the toolbar a couple of times.

The two icons look like a file with a tight belt around it, and a file with a refresh symbol on top of it.

If I switch files by double-clicking them in the Package Explorer, there is no delay, whether or not the file was already open.

What is causing this delay and how do I stop it?

Comment: Do you see any running jobs in the `Progress` view meanwhile?

Comment: Nope, it says no operations running.

Comment: Can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Goto `eclipse.ini` file, change the below from `1.5` to `1.6` from `Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5` to `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6`.